# Win32 App (Aero): Prevent dialog move

Tags: winapi, user-interface, win32gui

I've a dialog based Win32-app on Win7-Aero which only displays a dialog. The dialog should have a title bar. I don't want that the user can move the dialog on the screen.

I've no luck so far... handling `WM_NCHITTEST`, `WM_SYSCOMMAND`... setting `SWP_NOMOVE`.

What is the best way to achieve `NoMove`? I think DWM changes something on Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by handling `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and when you see an attempted move, change the coordinates back to where they should be. E.g.

```
switch (uMsg)
{
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
        if (!(reinterpret_cast<LPWINDOWPOS>(lParam)->flags & SWP_NOMOVE))
        {
            reinterpret_cast<LPWINDOWPOS>(lParam)->x = g_iMyXCoord;
            reinterpret_cast<LPWINDOWPOS>(lParam)->y = g_iMyYCoord;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

You would probably need to add some intelligence to this to distinguish between attempted moves by the user, and moves that your own program makes (or that the system makes if necessary - e.g. if a monitor disappears for instance).

Even though you say it doesn't work, I would have thought you could also do this by trapping `WM_NCHITTEST` and returning `HTBORDER` whenever `HTCAPTION` would have been returned - however you would have to do this by sub-classing the window rather than in the `DialogProc` (because you would need to call the default handler first and then process/change the return value). Same for `WM_SYSCOMMAND` (to catch moves the user attempts via the system menu).

Comment: Thank you.
In the meantime I found:

    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
    {
      if (MakeFixedWindow)
      {
        LPWINDOWPOS p = (LPWINDOWPOS)lParam;
        p->flags = SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE;
      }
      return TRUE;
    }

*MakeFixedWindow* goes true, if initial loading/displaying is finished.